# How to set the initial value of radDropDownList in requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, telerik

I have a dropdownlist 
I want to set the requiredfieldvalidator for the dropdownlist (stateComboBox)
Now my question is how can i set initial value for stateComboBox in my RequiredFieldValidator.
Thanks in advance

```css
<td>
  <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="stateComboBox" runat="server" DataTextField="SateCode" 
   DataValueField="SateCode" Width="173px">
  </telerik:RadDropDownList>
</td>



 <td>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvfState" runat="server" ControlToValidate="stateComboBox"
  ErrorMessage="State is Required" ForeColor="#CC0000">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the code behind you can use

```
rvfState.InitialValue =
```

I guess you will need to grab the first object from your data object. so if it is a DataTable you could say `rvfState.InitialValue = dt.rows[0]["SateCode"]`